# How to get the list of non empty queries?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access I have 1 table that updates daily via external file and 50 queries (named  01_query, 02_query... 50_query), all with same columns and logic but with different filters.  Some returns result, others are empty.

How can I get the list (using another query) with the names of NON empty queries?

I found the way to get a list of all query names with this code

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (Left$([Name],1)<>"~") AND (MSysObjects.Type)=5
ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name
```

but I can't figure out how to filter out the "empty" queries.

Comment: Is the list supposed to be a string containing query names separated by commas or something else?

Comment: just a list that i can view, a table, a list, a pop up ... 
the purpose is to avoid opening all days all the queries to check if there is something inside

Comment: The query in your question ... does it return only the names of those 50 queries which you described ... or are there other queries whose names don't match the XX_query pattern and which should be ignored.

Comment: yes, there are other queries that don't match the xx_query pattern and must be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely must have an Access SQL solution to produce your list, consider something other than `UNION` of 50 data sources.  Access does not allow you to `UNION` an unlimited number of data sources, but I don't recall what that limit is.  And even if it allows you to `UNION` 50, I still wouldn't do it.

I tested this one in Access 2010 and it produces the result I think you're looking for.  Since you've demonstrated you have read permission on `MsysObjects` it should work for you, too.

```sql
SELECT
    sub.Name
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            m.Name,
            IIf(
                m.Name ALike '[0-9][0-9][_]query' AND m.Type=5,
                DCount('*', m.Name),
                0
               ) AS non_empty_target_query
        FROM MsysObjects AS m
    ) AS sub
WHERE sub.non_empty_target_query=True
ORDER BY sub.Name;
```

The `IIf()` expression is the key to this query.  In human-like speak it says, if the object is a query and its name starts with 2 digits followed by an underscore followed by "query", return the count of rows from that query; otherwise just return zero.

Then the parent query filters away those rows where `non_empty_target_query` is zero (False), leaving only rows containing the names of your "non-empty" queries.

Comment: Just tried this solution, absolutely perfect. 
Exactly what I was looking for. I had already tried to use IIf function without success. Now I'm going to study "why" it works ;)
Thank you  HansUp

Comment: I added some explanation about how it works.  Once you understand how the `IIf` works, I hope the rest makes sense.

Comment: Perfect, greatly appreciated. TY

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all your queries follow the same format, you actually don't need to do anything with `MSysObjects`. You can just do a simple loop (in VBA):

```
Public Sub GetNonEmptyQueries()
   Dim db As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
   Dim queryName As String
   Dim i As Integer

   Set db = CurrentDb

   For i = 1 To 50
      queryName = format(i, "00") & "_query"
      Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(format(i, "00") & "_query")
      Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset

      If rs.recordCount > 0 Then
         ' do whatever you need to do with the query name here
         Debug.Print qdf.Name
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

If you don't want to use VBA, it's possible to write a query that `UNION`s the `COUNT(*)` of all your queries. Something like this:

```
SELECT "01_query" AS QueryName,  Count(*) AS [Count] FROM 01_query HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
UNION
SELECT "02_query",  COUNT(*) FROM 02_query HAVING count(*) > 0
...
UNION
SELECT "50_query", COUNT(*) FROM 50_query HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Of course, you're going to have to add all the queries by hand, which is going to get rather tedious. I think the time you would spend hand-writing such a query might be better-spent reading up on VBA, so you can use the first option. :)

Comment: Thank you Zack,  I'm very newbie in SQL and totally ignore VBA so i take your hint  as my next step in my coding evolution :) I'll try to understand and apply it.
Anyway ..  just for my information, there is no way to achieve the result via a "simple" SQL query?

Comment: You can write a series of union queries, but it's going to be tedious. I'll update my answer so you can see what it would look like.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it as answered.

Comment: Ok, used the SQL method on a subset and it works as expected. Thanks Zack for the 2 versions. Undoubtedly the VBA version is much more powerful and elegant but not mastering VBA it is much more difficult to me to add any variations to the code, so i'll go with the SQL method for now. TY!